# Error on setting the Mysql_config environment variable

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to install [this](http://nodejsdb.org/db-mysql/) database driver for Node.js, for which I'm supposed to specify the MYSQL_CONFIG environment variable through

`$ export MYSQL_CONFIG=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`

prior to running `$ npm install db-mysql` but I'm getting this error in the terminal.

```
bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/usr/bin/mysql_config': not a valid identifier
```

I don't get what's going on. Please help!

Comment: Can you please make sure you have the MySQL client libraries installed in your system ? Is the path to access to the configuration is correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export MYSQL_CONFIG=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

should be OK.

Make sure there is no space before or after the `=`.

Comment: No idea where did that pesky little space came from. Thanks!